# Number of solutions to $\cos^7x+\cos^7(x+2\pi/3)+\cos^7(x+4\pi/3) = 0$ in $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a trigonometry problem which I am trying to solve for a lot of time, but nothing seems to work, here it is:

> $$\cos^7x + \cos^7(x+2\pi/3) + \cos^7(x + 4\pi/3) = 0$$
>   We have to find the number of solutions of $x$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

I have tried to expand it with $\cos(A+B)$ identity, and tried to find any boundedness, but nothing seems to be working.

Any help with be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let set $\begin{cases}c=\cos(x) & C=\frac c2\\ s=\sin(x) &S=\frac{s\sqrt{3}}2\end{cases}\quad$ then we can write $\begin{cases}\cos(x+\frac{2\pi}3)=-C-S\\ \cos(x+\frac{4\pi}3)=-C+S\end{cases}$

Thus we need to expand:

$E =(2C)^7+(-C-S)^7+(-C+S)^7$
$\require{cancel}\begin{align} \\\hphantom{mmm}& =128C^7 \\
& -C^7-\cancel{7C^6S}-21C^5S^2-\cancel{35C^4S^3}-35C^3S^4-\cancel{21C^2S^5}-7CS^6-\cancel{S^7} \\
& -C^7+\cancel{7C^6S}-21C^5S^2+\cancel{35C^4S^3}-35C^3S^4+\cancel{21C^2S^5}-7CS^6+\cancel{S^7} \\\\
&= 126C^7-42C^5S^2-70C^3S^4-14CS^6 \\\\
&= 14\,C\ (9C^6-3C^4S^2-5C^2S^4-S^6) \\\\
&\overset{(*)}{=} 14\,C(C^2-S^2)(3C^2+S^2)^2\end{align}$

(*) Note that in the original expression of $E$ when you set $C=S$ or $C=-S$ then $E=(2C)^7+(-2C)^7+0=0$, this is the reason that guides us into factorising $(C-S)(C+S)=(C^2-S^2)$ out of this polynomial.

We can notice that $\begin{cases}3C^2+S^2=\frac 34(c^2+s^2)=\frac 34 \\\\ C^2-S^2=\frac 14(c^2-3s^2)=\frac 14(4c^2-3)\end{cases}\quad$  using twice $c^2+s^2=1$.

Finally $$E=\frac{63}{64}(4c^3-3c)=\frac{63}{64}\cos(3x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$

Thus, $$a^7+b^7+c^7=$$
$$=2187u^7-5103u^5v^2+3402u^3v^4-567uv^6+567u^4w^3-567u^2v^2w^3+63v^4w^3+21uw^6.$$
But $$\cos{x} + \cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) +\cos\left(x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)=0.$$
Thus, $$\cos^7{x} + \cos^7\left(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) +\cos^7\left(x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)=0$$ it's
$$\cos{x}\cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\cos\left(x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)\cdot$$
$$\cdot\left(\cos{x} \cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) +\cos{x}\cos\left(x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) +\cos\left(x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)\cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right)=0.$$
Also, we can show that:
$$\cos{x} \cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) +\cos{x}\cos\left(x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) +\cos\left(x+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)\cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=-\frac{3}{4}.$$

Another way:

Since $a+b+c=0$, we obtain:
$$0=a^7+b^7+c^7=a^7+b^7-(a+b)^7=$$
$$=-(7a^6b+21a^5b^2+35a^4b^3+35a^3b^4+21a^2b^5+7ab^6)=$$
$$=-7ab(a^5+b^5+3ab(a^3+b^3)+5a^2b^2(a+b))=$$
$$=7abc(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4+3ab(a^2-ab+b^2)+5a^2b^2)=$$
$$=7abc(a^4+2a^3b+3a^2b^2+2ab^3+b^4)=7abc(a^2+ab+b^2)^2=7abc(ab+ac+bc)^2.$$

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks a lot for breaking it down.

Comment: How did you get that indentity? By the binomial expansion of $(a + b + c)^7$ ?

Comment: @Zlytherin Yes, of course, but also,  I work with symmetric polynomials and I just know this identity. But you can use Wolfram-Alpha. Do you want that I'll give a link?

Comment: But if we expand that using binomial it would be a lot of work. How could we be able to expand that in an exam? Is there any alternative way to prove that? And without computer of course?

Comment: @Zlytherin I am ready to show. Just we know now that $u=0$

Comment: @Zlytherin I added something. See now.

Comment: There is probably something wrong the original expression is $\frac{63}{64}\cos(3x)$ and is not identically $0$.

Comment: @zwim We need to solve an equation. It's not an  identity.

Answer (score 0):

As $\cos3\left(x+\dfrac{2n\pi}3\right)=\cdots=\cos3x,$

$d_r=\cos\left(x+\dfrac{2n\pi}3\right);r=0,1,2$

are roots of the equation $$4t^3-3t-\cos3x=0$$

Let $d_0=a,f_1=b,d_2=c$

Using Vieta's formula,
$$a+b+c=\dfrac04$$

$$ab+bc+c=-\dfrac34$$

$$4abc=-\cos3x$$

$$\implies a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=?$$

$$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc=?$$

$$4(a^4+b^4+c^4)=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)\cos3x=?$$

$$4(a^5+b^5+c^5)=3(a^3+b^3+c^3)+(a^2+b^2+c^2)\cos3x=?$$

$$4(a^7+b^7+c^7)=3(a^5+b^5+c^5)+(a^4+b^4+c^4)\cos3x=?$$